# Narayana numbers as character values?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups

The Catalan numbers show up as character values of the symmetric group: Let $\lambda = (n,n)$, a partition with two parts. Then $\chi^\lambda(1^{2n}) = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$, the $n$:th Catalan number.

Is there a natural family of partitions and permutation types that gives the [Narayana numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana_number), $\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{k-1}$?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to think that there would be?  (I know no reason to think that there wouldn't be, but it seems that one could ask an infinite family of questions of this form, and I'd be interested to know what makes this one seem like the right one.)

Comment: This is not answering your question about symmetric group representations, but here is an algebraic context in which the Narayana numbers arise naturally: take the irreducible $\mathrm{Sp}_{2n}$ (symplectic group) representation of highest weight $\omega_n$, and restrict it to $GL_n \subseteq \mathrm{Sp}_{2n}$; then this representation decomposes into $n+1$ irreducible $GL_n$ reps of dimensions $N(k,n)$, the Narayana numbers. See Proctor "New symmetric plane partition identities..."

Comment: Have you checked https://oeis.org/A001263 and A134264?

Comment: And the refined Narayana numbers https://oeis.org/A125181

Comment: Clickable link for @SamHopkins's [suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343590/narayana-numbers-as-character-values#comment859072_343590):  [Proctor - New symmetric plane partition identities from invariant theory work of De Concini and Procesi](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S019566981380128X) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1059559)).